# How to convert standard color names in string to UIColor values

Tags: ios, swift, string, colors, uicolor

I have a variable:

```
var colorName = String()
```

I need the tint color of a button to be the appropriate color. Doing the following:

```
cell.btn.tintColor = UIColor.red
```

works for me. But I need to use my colorName variable instead of "UIColor.red" expression.

How would I initialize a `UIColor` with the string `red` to be `UIColor.red`?

Comment: If you put your colors in the asset catalog, you can then use [`UIColor(named:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/2877380-init).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in feature to make a UIColor with a name. You can write an extension like the one by [Paul Hudson](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/about) found here: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uicolor/how-to-convert-a-html-name-string-into-a-uicolor

Simplified example:

```
extension UIColor {
    public func named(_ name: String) -> UIColor? {
        let allColors: [String: UIColor] = [
            "red": .red,
        ]
        let cleanedName = name.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "").lowercased()
        return allColors[cleanedName]
    }
}
```

And then use it:

```
let redColor = UIColor().named("red")
```

You could also define an xcassets like in this article: https://medium.com/bobo-shone/how-to-use-named-color-in-xcode-9-d7149d270a16

And then use `UIColor(named: "red")`

Comment: Thanks. It looks too much lines of code for me. 
I don't need to define my own colors.
My colorName var can only contain a proven standard values of UIColor (e.g.: "white", "systemTeal", "systemGray4" etc.)
I still hope I can find more elegant solution.

Comment: What do you mean a proven standard?

Comment: I made a simplified version, you can checkout. There's no other way to go from `String` to `UIColor`

Comment: I mean standard names as they are in Apple documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/standard_colors

Comment: The simplified example looks great - I will try it :)

Comment: @Akrastan I would create a computed property extending StringProtocol

Comment: @LeoDabus that's more complicated. My first answer to this (see edits) was similar to that idea.

Comment: It works for me - no need for cleaning, so I've put out the cleaning line.

Answer (score 0):

As there is no pre-defined method to do this so we need to create a custom method for this, so you can use the method defined below:-

```
func chooseColor(_ name: String) -> UIColor{
    switch name {
    case "red":
        return UIColor.red //or you can use hex colors here
    case "blue":
        return UIColor.blue
    case "brown":
        return UIColor.brown
    case "green":
        return UIColor.green
    case "yellow":
        return UIColor.yellow
    default :
        return UIColor.black
    }
    
}
```

Then, you can access it by calling it like called in the statement below:-

```
 cell.btn.tintColor = chooseColor("red")
```